# unable to find "Common Language Runtime support" setting

Tags: c++, visual-studio

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2008, C++

I am trying to solve this error "fatal error C1190: managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option" with reference of,

1] [Managed target code requires a '\clr' option : Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099926/managed-target-code-requires-a-clr-option-error)

2] http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?418133-How-to-run-a-very-long-SQL-statement

3] https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34844476-8e2f-4947-b715-eb69edaf60d9/fatal-error-c1190-managed-targeted-code-requires-a-clr-option?forum=vclanguage

but unable to find "Common Language Runtime support" setting, can anyone please help how to fix this error? or Which path to enable the /clr option in Visual Studio 2008

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: I suggest you could install the `C++/CLI supprot` And Then you could try to [create a CLR projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-create-clr-empty-projects?view=vs-2019). File-> New -> Project -> Visual c++ ->CLR

Comment: Hmm, that was not optional in VS2008.  [Screenshot](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/set_build_options_vs2008.htm).

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT unable to find it for visual studio 2008, can you you help? to find C++/CLI supprot .

Comment: I think you may need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=29)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT that solution not meeting with required compatible settings

Comment: According to the [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/), Microsoft's official platform no longer provides download and installation of visual studio 2008. So i couldn't reproduce your problem. I suggest you could try to use visual studio 2019.